# Syntax error on subsequent destructure assignments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to execute a series of API call and use destructure assignments:

```
let {data, pagination} = await api_call("param1");
let {data} = await api_call("param2");
```

This snipset raises a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Identifier 'data' has already been declared
```

Can I use 2 destructure assignments one after the other like this ? If so, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A variable can only be declared once. It's mutable so you can change it's value but you cannot declare same variable thus the error you're getting, so either:

```
let {data, pagination} = await api_call("param1");
let {data2} = await api_call("param2");
```

or

```
let {data, pagination} = await api_call("param1");
({data} = await api_call("param2"));
```

Notice how you need `()` around it in the second case, because otherwise the `{` looks like the beginning of a block to the parser.

Comment: Your second code block has^H^H^H had a syntax error, you need `()` around the destructuring pattern (otherwise, the `{` looks like the beignning of a block to the parser). *Edit:* I took the liberty of adding that.

Comment: The idea is to keep the same names for all the return values (it's like GET requests with different query parameters so you expect to have the same return variables available). The second solution is awesome !